# Enable the AI using Application Insights Status Monitor but SQL Dependencies in Command property is not showing the generated SQL

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, iis-10

I was hosted my ASP.NET web application into local IIS server, then enable the Application Insights by using Application Insights Status Monitor by following this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now#a-namequestionsaquestions-about-status-monitor).

After configuration done, then I went to azure portal and open my application insights resource for seeing the dependency calls, requests, and exceptions everything coming nicely. The problem is that SQL Dependencies in Command property is not showing the generated SQL.

I can only see `<server_name> | <database_name>,` whereas in the other app I can see the whole query. See the below image for more information about my issue.

[image]

But After some time, I received the notification in status monitor like this below figure.

[image]

Can you please tell how to resolve the above issue as soon as possible?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: Found more about it: https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/427

Comment: @rfcdejong, still I am facing same issue.

Comment: One time I had it working on a service and that link I posted in the comment was going to fix it again for another service, but sadly it didn't.

Comment: it is suddenly working after a new deployment.. I guess you will have to install the extension first and then reboot and redeploy. start/stop perhaps. Something along the road. But that extension in the link above is certainly the solution